# Binding Validation.Errors

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, mvvm

I want to bind the `Validation.Errors` property of my WPF window to a property on my ViewModel, but it says that `Validation.Errors` doesn't have a setter-object.

I just want to bind it one way to my ViewModel. How can I do this?

Comment: In MVVM view model is a source of validation errors. Why do you want to get validation errors from *view*?

Comment: You can't, because that's not how it works.  IDEI or INDEI as @eli said.

Comment: I just want to disable my save button if there are errors.

Comment: @ErikBender For disabling a button with MVVM, you should be using the `.CanExecute` of whatever `ICommand` the button is bound to. I would also recommend using `IDataErrorInfo` for validation with WPF/MVVM though. :)

Comment: I have implemented IDataErrorInfo in my model class, but how do i check this in my viewmodel?

Comment: @ErikBender I usually add an `.IsValid` property that loops through validated property names and returns true if there are any errors for that. Implementation usually looks something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7391464/302677).

Comment: Ok, if I create base classes (ModelBase and ViewModelBase), do I have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged and INotifyDataErrorInfo in both?